# Force LF line endings, and convert working directory without commit

Tags: git, newline, gitattributes, core.autocrlf

Consider the following situation: A git repository exists, containing text files with both CRLF and LF line endings.

I'd like to

1. Enforce all future *commits* to be converted to LF
2. Enforce all future *clones* to be checked out in LF
3. <del>Convert my local index to only use LF</del> *see comments*
4. Convert my local working directory to only use LF

I can do 1. easily with `* text=auto eof=lf` in `.gitattributes`.

But is there any way to do 2. and 4. **without a mass-change commit**, and without affecting existing history?

I suppose converting the local index is not possible, but if 1. and 4. works, it shouldn't be required.

I've read and tried almost every combination of `core.autocrlf`, `.gitattributes` options, and `git checkout/rm/checkout-index/reset` permutation without success.

Comment: Given that the line endings are part of the content of your tree, I don't see how you can alter the tree _without_ a mass commit.

Comment: @JonahBishop, that's what I figured. Thank you for confirming my suspicion, I have changed the question accordingly.